# Void pointers in an event system

Tags: c, events

I'm writing an event system where the programmer can make his own events, but I'm having an issue with void pointers for passing event data. The event system works roughly like this:

```
typedef enum { ... USER_EVENT ...} event_type;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    void* data;
} user_event;

typedef struct {
    event_type type;
    union {
        ...
        user_event user;
        ...
    };
} event;
```

So I'm writing a user event, using my own custom structure, and passing it to this function:

```
void add_user_event(int id, void* data) {
    event e;
    user_event u;
    u.id = id;
    u.data = data;
    e.type = USER_EVENT;
    e.user = u;
    add_event(e); /* add_event is just a function that adds the event to the event stack, and it works fine with predefined events */
}
...
add_user_event(my_user_event_id, (void*)&data);
```

And then I retrieve it like this:

```
...
if (e.type == USER_EVENT && e.user.id == the_user_id) {
    user_data_struct data = *(user_data_struct*) e.user.data;
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Thing is, this should work, but it doesn't (it just gives completely garbled data). I am certain that the data *given* was alright (made some checks), but then it somehow doesn't get the correct data (maybe a bad pointer location?). Some other hints, if this could help, is that the `add_user_event` call is made within a function (and the event is defined within the function). Could this affect anything?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: In `add_user_event(my_user_event_id, (void*)&data);` how is `data` defined ? Could it be an object local to some function ?

Comment: @cnicutar, yes, the "object" is defined within a function, if that's what you mean.

Comment: And does it survive long enough for you to dereference it ?

Comment: @cnicutar I have no idea. How long does a variable defined within a function normally survive?

Comment: *"add_event is just a function that adds the event to the event stack"*: I don't suppose that event stack is a stack of *pointers* and not actual `event` structures? If it is storing pointer addresses only, you're saving off addresses to local-scope variables, which are invalid as soon as that scope is left.

Comment: Until the function invocation ends. I.e. until the closing `}` is reached.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try using another method for storing the events.

Comment: @cnicutar, if you turned your comment into an answer, I could give you the bounty, as it was the correct answer

Comment: @MiJyn I think it would be best if you yourself provide an answer describing the problem and the solution. I would upvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue, as [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) pointed out, was not related to the void pointers or anything, it was simply because the data for the event was stored within a function (the event handler was called after the function finished executing, therefore the data was destroyed before it could even access it).

So this was my original code:

```
void fire_my_event() {
    my_event_structure ev;
    /* do stuff with ev */
    add_user_event(my_event_id, (void*)&ev);
}
/* ev is now destroyed, before the event handler could be called */
```

I fixed it by making `ev` "global", like this:

```
my_event_structure ev;

void fire_my_event() {
    /* reset ev and set values */
    add_user_event(my_event_id, (void*)&ev);
}
/* ev will not be destroyed until the end of the program */
```

Comment: This is not threadsafe, or even safe against multiple events.  If `fire_my_event` gets called twice before the event is resolved, then you're the value of the `ev` struct will be changed "right out from under the nose of" the first event handler.  It would be better to `malloc()` a new struct every time you fire an event, and `free()` it at the end of the handler.

Comment: @sheu, yes, I thought about using that, but in my application, it is impossible for that to happen.

Comment: never say never.  Better to be safe now, then to spend a day later debugging why your events don't work :-).  It's a good habit, and it keeps you from using a global variable, which is another habit to avoid.

Comment: @sheu, oh, I see now, for some reason I thought you were talking about a dynamic array. Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Rather than making it global, you should keep it declared inside of `fire_my_event` as `static my_event_structure ev;`.  This way it's only scoped to the function, but is permanently allocated instead of existing on the stack just for the duration of the function.

Comment: @tomlogic, thanks for the suggestion, I always forget about them :/